# Нужна ли запятая после слов "при прочтении"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> ...показал всю тяжесть военной жизни, и при прочтении я сам как-будто оказался в том времени.

Нужна ли запятая после слова *прочтении*?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, но выражение "при прочтении" звучит, так сказать, не очень. Если **во время чтения** герой как будто оказался в том времени, то можно сказать: "Читая это рассказ, я сам как будто оказался в том времени".

Answer (score 1):

...[Он, писатель, автор] *показал всю тяжесть военной жизни, и **при прочтении** я сам как будто оказался в том времени.*

Это сложносочиненное предложение, в котором имеется обстоятельство (когда?) в форме существительного с предлогом. И речь, конечно же, должна идти о двух запятых: перед и после "при прочтении".
Вот что о таких конструкциях говорится у Розенталя.

> **1.** Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова...

Пояснительных слов нет (это говорит в пользу необособления), а представленный отрывок настолько короток, что в нем невозможно увидеть никаких дополнительных причин для постановки запятых.

Язык ― одно из наиболее ярких отражений истории страны, и **при чтении газет «моих трех государств»** я вспомнил, как, например, Дания в свое время была большим государством... [А. А. Игнатьев. Пятьдесят лет в строю. Кн. 3 (1947-1953)]

[Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

**Дополнительно**
I. "При прочтении", считаю, можно оставить. Вот предложение с очень похожим смыслом.

Но эффект подражания, когда переносил на себя и действие книг и охвачен был вдруг неожиданно родственной стихией, будто в утробу попадал, чувствуя какое-то свое новое рождение, имел место только **при прочтении** Достоевского. [Валентин Курбатов. Дорога в объезд // «Дружба народов», 1999.09.15]

II. [Как будто](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE) пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

***...показал всю тяжесть военной жизни, и при прочтении я сам как-будто оказался в том времени.***

Могу **повторить дословно** мнение нашего участника: *Запятая не нужна, но выражение "при прочтении" звучит, так сказать, не очень. Если во время чтения герой как будто оказался в том времени, то можно сказать: "**Читая** это рассказ, я сам как будто оказался в том времени".*

**Очевидно,** что одиночное обстоятельство не требует обособления, поэтому основное внимание уделено **правильности грамматической формы** "при прочтении". Действительно, герой рассказа оказался в другом времени именно **при чтении, а не после того, как уже прочитал книгу.**

... *имел место только при прочтении Достоевского*.  Здесь уже немного другое: подводится итог восприятия творчества Достоевского в целом,  поэтому форма "при прочтении" выглядит **более приемлемой**.